# insert data from a custom form in Joomla

Tags: php, joomla, joomla1.5, joomla-extensions

I need to create an "Acknoledgment" page that once a registered user reads, they hit I agree and stores their username and timestamp into a new table, (meabe I could use joomla's jos_users table).. What component or what would be the simplest way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create the form and integrate it into a Joomla article you may use [RS Form](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/contacts-and-feedback/forms/2265) 
(component for creation, plugin for integration). Then you may create menu item and make it accessable oly for registered users. All data will be stored in database and visible from Joomla admin.

I hope it is helpfull.